# jQuery Isotope works when not pressing F5

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I implemented jQuery Isotope into http://voicent.com/case-studies/

If you go to the URL normally, it works most the time. But, if you hit F5 it breaks everytime. I am not sure why it is acting weird, by working and sometimes not working.

Is this a bug with Isotope, or something wrong with my implementation?

My localhost copy works perfectly 99% of the time when I hit F5.

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(
                function() {
            // init Isotope
            var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
                itemSelector: '.element-item',
                layoutMode: 'fitRows',
                isResizeBound: true
            });
            // filter functions
            var filterFns = {
                // show if number is greater than 50
                numberGreaterThan50: function() {
                    var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
                    return parseInt(number, 10) > 50;
                },
                // show if name ends with -ium
                ium: function() {
                    var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
                    return name.match(/ium$/);
                }
            };
            // bind filter button click
            $('.filters-button-group').on('click', 'li', function() {
                var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                $('.tags__link--active').removeClass('tags__link--active');
                $(this).addClass('tags__link--active');
                // use filterFn if matches value
                filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
                $grid.isotope({filter: filterValue});
            });
            // change is-checked class on buttons
            $('.button-group').each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
                var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
                $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function() {
                    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
                    $(this).addClass('is-checked');
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: How are you including jQuery in the page? Could be a race condition; on localhost or when accessing the page via the browser bar - which will probably hit the browser's cache - scripts are loaded almost instantly so they are already loaded when your source is executed. When F5 is pressed, the browser might do a fresh fetch and the script download takes "too long". Also, does the developer console say anything (errors)?

Comment: No  errors in the debug console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The problem

The images probably cause your issue. Since you isotope is initiating on the DOM ready, the images hasn't been loaded entirely, messing up the calculs of isotope for positioning.

Why does it work on local machine or when accessing the URL directly? That is because on the local machine, the loading time is really fast (almost instant) so the calculs are fine. On the distant server, the images are cached on your computer, so the request is really fast as well. When pressing F5, the browser isn't getting the images in the cache, but making a new request.

## The solution

If you check out the faq of [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/faq.html), you'll see the first question is exactly your problem :

> ## How do I fix overlapping item elements?
>
> If your layout has images, you probably need to use [imagesLoaded](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html#imagesloaded).
>
> Overlaping items are caused by items that change size after a layout. This is caused by unloaded media: images, [web fonts](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html#web-fonts), embedded buttons. To fix it, you need to initialize or `layout` after all the items have their proper size.

So after the reading, the solution is to add to your code (after the initialisation of Isotope) those lines:

```
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.isotope('layout');
});
```

Comment: I added more code, for when imagesLoaded, can you look again? In the mean time I will try window.load

Comment: jQuery(window).load fixed it I believe

Comment: @Illuminati Wait, you had `imagesLoaded`? I just changed my answer cause `window.load` is a pretty bad advice... `imagesLoaded` is supposed to work...